# Correct way of using jQuery's .wrap() on a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having troulbe wrapping some HTML with jQuery's `.wrap()` method:

I have:

```
var containerbox = $(".identifier:eq("+i+")").parent().html();
```

And want to wrap the `containerbox` variable in a div, so I have tried:

```
containerbox = $(containerbox).wrap('<div class="holder" />');
```

With no success.

I have also tried:

```
var containerbox = $(".identifier:eq("+i+")").parent().html().wrap('<div class="holder" />');
```

And:

```
var containerbox = $(".identifier:eq("+i+")").parent().html();
containerbox.wrap(function() {
 containerbox += '<div class="holder">' + $(this).text() + '</div>';
});
```

Does anyone know the correct way of achieving this?

Comment: You can use `$(".identifier").eq(i)` to avoid ugly selector.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
var containerbox = $('.identifier').eq(i).parent();
containerbox.wrap('<div class="holder" />');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8YKY4/)

Comment: Thanks but that still throws me "Uncaught TypeError: Object"

Comment: @MeltingDog it looks fine in http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8YKY4/3/ the error could be coming from some other code